# Ethernet to USB adapter is not initialized as ttyUSB or ttyACM device

Tags: linux, devices, usb-device, ttyusb

When I plug a Ethernet-to-USB adapter to my Ubuntu 14.04 on the USB port. I can see the Ubuntu has an extra ethernet device. However, I want to see /dev/ttyACM* type of device.

I'm wondering why the /dev/ttyACM* is not created.

I'm using the plugable USB 2.0 Ethernet Adapater.

Thanks,

Comment: What does `lsusb` tell you? (and then `lsusb -v <the device you is the ethernet USB adapter>`)

Comment: `lsusb` shows the device name. However, there is no /dev/ttyUSB or /dev/ttyACM file. I need the /dev/ttyACM file to read the device

Comment: If the device does not implement a feature, how the feature could be detected by the OS on that device? Would you mind to add `lsusb -v` output for your USB ethernet stick?