# Ethernet to USB adapter is not initialized as ttyACM device

Tags: linux, devices, usb-device, ttyusb

I have a similar question to the one posted here [Ethernet to USB adapter is not initialized as ttyUSB or ttyACM device](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/293493/ethernet-to-usb-adapter-is-not-initialized-as-ttyusb-or-ttyacm-device) where I am trying to connect a geomagic touch device which is connected to a Linux machine (Ubuntu 14.04.2 Trusty) via an ethernet-usb adapter. According to the instructions provided by the vendor (Linux_helper_notes.pdf https://3dsystems.teamplatform.com/pages/102863?t=fptvcy2zbkcc), the device should be recognized as a ttyACM device but instead, it is being recognized as a network device. I have set it with link-local IPv4 as instructed.

The output of "lsusb -v" is the following:

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0424:7500 Standard Microsystems Corp. LAN7500 Ethernet 10/100/1000 Adapter
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass          255 Vendor Specific Class
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol       255 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0424 Standard Microsystems Corp.
  idProduct          0x7500 LAN7500 Ethernet 10/100/1000 Adapter
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           1 WS
  iProduct                2 USB Gigabit LAN
  iSerial                 3 0000000ce6
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           39
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          4 Cfg
    bmAttributes         0xc0
      Self Powered
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           3
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol    255 
      iInterface              5 i/f
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0010  1x 16 bytes
        bInterval               1
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
  bLength                10
  bDescriptorType         6
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass          255 Vendor Specific Class
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol       255 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  bNumConfigurations      1
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered
```

And the output of "dmesg | tail" is

```
[100046.831766] usb 1-5: Manufacturer: WS
[100046.831769] usb 1-5: SerialNumber: 0000000ce6
[100046.834946] smsc75xx v1.0.0
[100046.885691] smsc75xx 1-5:1.0 eth0: register 'smsc75xx' at usb-0000:00:14.0-5, smsc75xx USB 2.0 Gigabit Ethernet, **MAC_ADDRESS**
[100046.899593] smsc75xx 1-5:1.0 eth3: renamed from eth0
[100046.911256] systemd-udevd[10963]: renamed network interface eth0 to eth3
[100046.961743] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth3: link is not ready
[100049.063134] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth3: link becomes ready
[100049.063956] smsc75xx 1-5:1.0 eth3: link up, 100Mbps, half-duplex, lpa 0x0081
[100049.068943] smsc75xx 1-5:1.0 eth3: link up, 100Mbps, half-duplex, lpa 0x0081
```